# How to create events that are part of a 'graph'?

Tags: neo4j

I'm quite new.. I'm looking to do an event logs system with 
multiple "cycles" (a cycle is a chain of events), composed of events (each events can have 7 fixed types), each event has 4 contexts too.

I want to be able to create a structure mapping this 'system', in a graph database.

**Question 1: How to specify several "cycles" ?**
I want to be able to have a different cycles : Cycle 1, Cycle 2..etc with events (Events type 1 to 7) which can be created later. 
I need **Some kind of information/"state" keeping that events are "part of" a cycle.**

Actually I created 2 events like this : 1 Type3 and 1 Type 4 from the same Cycle of events.

> create (Type3:Type3_name {context1: "John Doe", context2: "blah blah", >context3: "127.0.0.1", context4: "email"})
>
> create (Type4:Type4_name {context1: "", context2: "some characteristics", >context3: "127.0.0.1", context4: ""})

How to map/create this "cycle" of events, i.e to know that the events are part of the same cycle ?

Later I want to be able to create other events that are part of other cycles...

**The events may have a unique id with a timestamp.**

In the future **and just for information** I want to be able to ask complex questions :
- Give me all Cycles where events have these context3 equal X..
- Give me all Cycles where there are a suite of event of type 2 having context2 = X and context3 = Y
I want to be able also to graph all the things !

### ASCII art :

>

> ```
>                            Cycle 1             
>                            *******                
>
>                           context1          
>                              |
>                context2--Event type 1--context3
>                              |
>                           context4
>
>                              .
>
>                           context1
>                              |
>                context2--Event type 2--context3
>                              |
>                           context4
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards !
John

Comment: Neo4j lets you use: labels (for nodes), properties (for nodes), and relationships (between nodes). The challenge to you is how the concepts you mentioned (cycle, event, context) will map into the neo4j concepts available. Which of these will fit best as a label? Which as nodes? Which as properties? What kind of relationships will you use to connect your nodes and create a graph structure that can be sufficiently queried? As far as associations (like "cycles have chains of events"), where does order matter, and where it does, how will you model that in your graph?

Comment: Have you played around with the movies database (`:play movies` from the neo4j browser)? Seems like looking at some example databases and queries might give you a better feel for how to model your data